# Chrome dev tools are slow

Tags: windows, google-chrome, performance, google-chrome-devtools

When I use Chrome dev tools it is unbearably slow. The scrolling in a source file (JS) takes cca 1s before jumping to next location. Selection of a text in source file takes also cca 1s. I had to blackbox all minified files, because it would take several seconds before the Chrome dev tools unfroze (when I accidentally opened them in source panel).

I read several discussions:

- [Google Chrome Developer Toolkit is Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125006/google-chrome-developer-toolkit-is-slow)
- [Google Chrome developer tools works very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36913727/google-chrome-developer-tools-works-very-slow)

and tried the proposed solutions, but nothing of the following helped:

- Turning on/off HW acceleration in Chrome settings
- Clearing cache
- New installation of Chrome
- Updating drivers of the graphic cards
- Ensure no workspace is specified
- Turning off all Javascript enhancements in dev tools settings(Brackets, Autoshow of variables)

It must be most likely something in the operating system. I tried updating the graphic card drivers, but to no avail (Intel HD 4000). Also, when I tried to run Chrome dev tools in VMware image, the performance was fine (on the same computer). I have now Windows 10, but before that I had Windows 8.1 and the problem was the same.

Besides reinstalling the whole system, any ideas?

Comment: I had the same issue with chrome and overall system performance after windows 10 anniversary update. I am using usb flash drive for ready boost and performance is good now. This might not be the correct solution but worked for me.

Comment: Thanks Akshay. I do not have the anniversary update yet. In my case the perf of system is ok. The problem is only with the chrome dev tools ...